# Center image within div on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I created a custom Instagram feed for my website and am trying to make the images enlarge to the center of the parent div on hover and am having difficulty achieving this.

I was able to sort-of make this happen earlier (and have since changed the code), but I have 2 rows of 4 images each being displayed and the ones on the ends (left or right) always get cut-off. It's like the containing div isn't wide enough. As of right now When you hover over the images, the image pops out but gets cut-off on ALL sides. I have tried many different things to make this happen to no avail.

I am using CSS to obtain the results, see code below. I am certain some of the code is redundant and confusing, so I apologize in advance! Thanks!

// Parent div

```
.instagram_feed {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

// This sets the sizing of the grid itself

```
#instagram-feed1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: 4em;
}
```

// Controls size of images in the grid

```
.instagram_feed .instagram_new {
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  padding:0 0px 5px 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
.instagram_feed img.insta-image {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
  -ms-transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
  -o-transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
}
  
.instagram_feed .insta-link {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  background:#232323;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

// Hover setttings

```
.instagram_feed .insta-image:hover {
  opacity: 100;
  background-color: rgb(41,47,51);
  position:absolute;
  transform: scale(2,2);
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  z-index:999;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease; 
}
```

Comment: Please add your markup and create a [example].

Answer (score 0):

```
 .instagram_feed {
   overflow:hidden;

   //position relative !!
   position: relative;
 }

.instagram_feed .insta-image:hover {
  //center
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2,2);

  opacity: 100;
  background-color: rgb(41,47,51);
  position:absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  z-index:999;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease; 
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed when I tried this :(

Comment: Could you show your HTML?